# How to add Basic authorization header in the Swagger in ASP .Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, .net-core, swagger-ui

How to add basic authorization header in Swagger in Asp .Net core. By default the api key treats as a query string but I need to customize that so that it will include in the header.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v5.0.0-rc2 see below:

```
   c.AddSecurityDefinition("Basic", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description = "Basic auth added to authorization header",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Scheme = "basic",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http
            });

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "Basic" }
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

after hours of tinkering I found this solution

first implement the IOperationFilter as below:

```
public class AddRequiredHeaderParameter : IOperationFilter
    {
        void IOperationFilter.Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var param = new Param();
            param.Name = "authorization";
            param.In = "header";
            param.Description = "JWT Token";
            param.Required = true;
            param.Type = "string";
            if (operation.Parameters == null)
                operation.Parameters = new List<IParameter>();
            operation.Parameters.Add(param);
        }
    }
```

then implement the interface IParameter

```
class Param : IParameter
    {

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string, object> Extensions { get {return new Dictionary<string, object>{{"test", true}};} }

        public string In { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Type { get; set; }

        public bool Required { get; set; }
    }
```

> the VERY important thing here is the Type property which is not
>   required by the interface but it has to be there as the swagger-ui
>   will need it

and finally hook it up to your swashbuckle config

```
services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.OperationFilter<AddRequiredHeaderParameter>();
    options.SingleApiVersion(new Info
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "Test",
        Description = "Test Service",
        TermsOfService = "None"
    });
    options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
});
```

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

Based on Mohsen's reply figured out we can do this without having to implement the Iparameter interface

```
public class AddRequiredHeaderParameter : IOperationFilter
{
    void IOperationFilter.Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Parameters == null)
            operation.Parameters = new List<IParameter>();
            operation.Parameters.Add(new NonBodyParameter
            {
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = "header",
                Description = "JWT Token",
                Required = true,
                Type = "string"
            });
    }
}
```

and finally hook it up to your swashbuckler config

```
    services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.OperationFilter<AddRequiredHeaderParameter>();
    options.SingleApiVersion(new Info
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "Test",
        Description = "Test Service",
        TermsOfService = "None"
    });
    options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[To place in swagger-ui navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVkce.png) you can use this code:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                ...
            });

            c.AddSecurityDefinition("JWT Token", new ApiKeyScheme
            {
                Description = "JWT Token",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = "header"
            });
        });
```

It will add JWT Token as Authorization header to every request.